# How can I get my CSS animation to run when clicking the button by usng jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit

I want my CSS animation to begin when i click on the button and due to the assignment brief instructions from my course at uni I must use jquery to do so can anybody help me?

```js
$('button').onClick(function(){
 $(".florence").addClass(".animate");
});
```

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#background {
 width:1024px;
 height:768px;
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
}
button {
 width:300px;
 height:100px;
 color:#1f1f1f;
 background-color:#fff;
 position:absolute;
 top:500px;
 left:300px;
 z-index:1;
}
.sky {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
} 
.grass {
 position:absolute;
 top:568px;
 left:0;
 float:left;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: grass;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: normal ease-out; 
}
.florence {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:600px;
 float:left;
 z-index:1;
}
.animate {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-name: florence;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: normal ease-out; 
}
.cloud1 {
 position:absolute;
 top:70px;
 left:50px;
 float:left;
 z-index:1;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: cloudone;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: normal ease-out; 
}
.cloud2 {
 position:absolute;
 top:192px;
 left:195px;
 float:left;
 z-index:1;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: cloudtwo;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: normal ease-out; 
}
.cloud3 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:515px;
 float:left;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: cloudthree;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: normal ease-out; 
}
.cloud4 {
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:670px;
 float:left;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: cloudfour;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: normal ease-out; 
}
.cloud5 {
 position:absolute;
 top:70px;
 left:914px;
 float:left;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: cloudfive;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: normal ease-out; 
}
.sun {
 position:absolute;
 top:25px;
 left:275px;
 float:left;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: sun;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: normal ease-out; 
}






@-webkit-keyframes cloudone {
    0% {
        top:-300px;
        left:100px;
    }
    70% {
     top:75px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 70px;
        left:50px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloudtwo {
    0% {
        top:-300px;
        left:50px;
    }
    70% {
     top:205px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 192px;
        left:195px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloudthree {
    0% {
        top:-150px;
        left:565px;
    }
    70% {
     top:110px;
    }
    100% {
        top:100px;
        left:515px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloudfour {
    0% {
        top:-200px;
        left:570px;
    }
    70% {
     top:15px;
    }
    100% {
        top:10px;
        left:670px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloudfive {
    0% {
        top:-300px;
        left:1014px;
    }
    70% {
     top:75px;
    }
    100% {
        top:70px;
        left:914px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes sun {
    0% {
        top:-300px;
        left:100px;
    }
    70% {
     top:65px;
    }
    100% {
        top:25px;
        left:275px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes florence {
    0% {
        left:1024px;
    }
    100% {
        left:600px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes grass {
    0% {
        top:590px;
    }
    100% {
        top:568px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Florence the Fluorescent Fuchsia</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="background">
   <button>Start</button>
   <img class="sky" src="images/sky.png">
   <img class="grass" src="images/grass.png">
   <img class="florence" class="animate" src="images/florence.png">
   <img class="cloud1" src="images/cloud1.png">
   <img class="cloud2" src="images/cloud2.png">
   <img class="cloud3" src="images/cloud3.png">
   <img class="cloud4" src="images/cloud4.png">
   <img class="cloud5" src="images/cloud5.png">
   <img class="sun" src="images/sun.png">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(el).click(function...)`, not `$(el).onClick(function...)`

Comment: Also, should be `.addClass('animate')`, not '.addClass('.animate')`. The addClass method assumes the class selector (.), so all you have to add is the class name.

Comment: I have done this also and still it isn't working

Comment: Have you tried both at once?

Comment: You need to clearly define what you mean by "*it isn't working;*" what precisely "*isn't working*"? What do you expect to happen, what happens instead? Have you reduced your code down to the *minimal* / *[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)* code possible to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: I have tried both at once and it isn't animating .florence at all. It's supposed to slide in from the right and its doesn't the rest of the CSS animations run when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/spq21jyj/

Comment: I can't understand how, it isn't working fine for me at all it isn't moving at all.

Comment: Okay I can see it working in js fiddle it must be an issue with linking the script.js

Comment: Do you have a javascript error in your console?

Comment: no errors, i really have no idea what is wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  $('button').on('click',function(){

     $(".florence").addClass("animate");
  });
```

You have a dot which you dont need in `addClass(".animate")`.
And its `click` insted of  `onClick` or alternativetly `on('click',function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

Your ".florence"-element has two class attributes. You need to write it like this:

```
<img class="florence animate" src="images/florence.png">
```

And adding the class "animate" a second time won't do anything (the Fiddle example from the comments only worked because the second class attribute gets ignored. If you click a second time on the button it won't work as well since the valid class attribute now has a animate class). You need to remove and add the class again. Unfortunatelly you can't do it right away like this:

```
$(".florence").removeClass("animate");
$(".florence").addClass("animate");
```

This will not work either for animations. You need to delay the second step a little:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(".florence").removeClass("animate");
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(".florence").addClass("animate");
     },1);
});
```

This works now. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spq21jyj/1/)